# Where does the SP (Stack Pointer) point to when the buffer is overflown?

Tags: buffer-overflow, stack-overflow

Let's consider a stack that grows downwards and a function that has a local variable for a buffer that takes 100 bytes of memory.

So, reading from top to bottom, it would be a 4-byte long return address, a 4-byte long OLD BP and the buffer.

Now, supposing that the user provided a 108-byte long input, there would be a buffer overflow. In this case, where does the SP point to?

Does it point to the return address or does it point to the buffer?

Comment: That would vary depending upon the processor itself.  Intel v Motorola v ARM etc would give you different answers.

Comment: Your question also depends on another dimension: time. The stack pointer will point to different places depending on which instruction within the program is currently executing. But since you are interested in a stack buffer overflow, I think you might mean "at time of return".